# Autocomplete not working

Tags: elpy

Elpy Configuration

```
Virtualenv........: None

RPC Python........: 2.7.10 (/usr/bin/python)

Interactive Python: ipython (not found)

Emacs.............: 25.2.1

Elpy..............: 1.16.0

Jedi..............: Not found (0.10.2 available)

Rope..............: Not found (0.10.5 available)

Importmagic.......: Not found (0.1.7 available)

Autopep8..........: Not found (1.3.2 available)

Yapf..............: Not found (0.16.3 available)

Syntax checker....: Not found (flake8)
```

Hello,
I have installed all the required packages (Jedi, Rop...) for elpy, but for some reason they seem not installed, also the autocomplete not working!, any idea ?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `(elpy-enable)` and `(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")` in your config and did you run `(jedi:install-server)` ?

Comment: Yes, (elpy-eneble) and (setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi") in my config file, and I did run jedi:install-server !!. I still have the problem !

Comment: You can open an issue on [github](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy)

Comment: Did you install the python packages in a virtual environment or with your system python? If you installed them in a virtual environment, you need to activate it using `pyvenv-activate`.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstood but did you install those packages only in emacs ? Because you need to install them also by using pip.

Open terminal and paste the following :

```
pip install jedi rope flake8 yapf importmagic
```

After that you should be all set.